# No such file or directory error when scraping Tweets using Tweepy in Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using the code below to pull specific tweets and save to a .json file format and keep getting the following error:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'data/greenroof.json'`

The code in question:

```py
import json
import tweepy

API_KEY = "key_here"
API_SECRET = "secret here"
TOKEN_KEY = "t_key_here"
TOKEN_SECRET = "t_secret_here"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

query = '#greenroof'
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, lang="en")

for page in cursor.pages():
    tweets = []
    for item in page:
        tweets.append(item._json)

with open('data/greenroof.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweets, outfile)
```

Please forgive the spacing of the above code, I cant appear to get it to present accurately.

I've used the mkdir data request on the command line, ensuring the path for said directory matches the location of script.

The error suggest that the file doesn't exist.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Oh, and go easy on me folks, total newbie to code & python.

Answer (score 1):

if the `data` directory is in your current working directory, make sure to add a `./` to the beginning of the path, signifying the current working directory.

i.e.
`with open('./data/greenroof.json', 'wb') as outfile:`